# AlamofireObjectMapper, nested JSON structure is always nil when serialized

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I am using `AlamofireObjectMapper` to serialize JSON responses from the server. Currently, with a get method I have the following structured JSON response:

```
 {
   data : {
      [
        { ID: 4, 
           ...
          PointList : {
             [
               {

               }, 
               {}
             ]
          }

        },
        {
          ...
        }

      ]
   }
 }
```

The outermost object i am defining as a custom `class` called `BrowsableObjectList` where I define the mapping to deserialize the json into the object as

```
class BrowsableObjectList : Mappable {
  var data : [BrowsableObject]?

  required init?(_ map: Map){
  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {
   data <- map["data"]
  } 
}
```

Similarly I define `BrowsableObject` as being

```
class BrowsableChronicle : Mappable {
  var pointList : [Point]?

  required init?(_ map: Map){}

  func mapping(map: Map) {
   pointList <- map["PointList"]
  }
}
```

Which refers to a list of `[Point]` where `Point` is a custom class defined as another mappable object.

```
class Point{
  var axisX : Int?
  var axisY : Int?

  required init?(_ map: Map){

  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {
   axisX <- map["AxisX"]
   axisY <- map["AxisY"]
  }
}
```

The problem is in my server call to the the endpoint, which I check in my browser as having values for `PointList` defined, is always `nil` when I access it.

Here is where I call the endpoint:

```
func getChronicleEntries(pageIndex: Int, pageSize : Int,  completionHandler: ([BrowsableChronicle]?, NSError?) -> ()){
print("page index is : \(pageIndex)")
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://myendpoint.com/getThing?", parameters: ["pageindex": "\(pageIndex)", "pagesize": "\(pageSize)"]).responseObject { (response: Response<BrowsableObjectList, NSError>) in
    if let userResponse = response.result.value {
      if let data = userResponse.data {
        let browsableObjectArray : [BrowsableObject] = data
        completionHandler(browsableObjectArray, nil)
      }
    } else {
      Logger.logSomething(response.result.error!.localizedDescription)
      completionHandler(nil, response.result.error)
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that `BrowsableObject.pointList` is always `nil` even though the endpoint returns the correct JSON list of `Point`s. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't set the innermost class as `Mappable`.

```
 class Point: Mappable{

 }
```

duh!